# Difference between np.max(x ,axis = 1) and x.max(axis = 1) for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, max

I am trying to get maximum value of each row of a numpy array matrix. I would like to achieve it efficiently and I came up with the following two idioms for doing this. My question is, is there any performance difference between the following two ways?

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])

np.max(x,axis = 1)
#array([3, 6, 9])

x.max(axis = 1)
#array([3, 6, 9])
```

Comment: Seems the real question here is whether these are two APIs to the same function, or are in fact two different functions, and how one might ever be able to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it out in a notebook and it seems your second method is slightly faster:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

First method:

```
%%timeit
np.max(x,axis = 1)

The slowest run took 11.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.71 µs per loop
```

Second method:

```
%%timeit
x.max(axis = 1)

The slowest run took 12.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.71 µs per loop
```

Presumably, this is because for the first one you will have call the numpy module, whereas for the second one, it is already in the object.

However, I would recommend against trying to optimize such small things, and first look at if you did the rest already (did you use a compiler like Numba, did you use a profiler to see what part of your code is slowing you down, etc.)